# Django hosting with Azure Web App Server Error 500

Tags: django, azure-web-app-service, hosting, web-hosting, internal-server-error

I followed this tutorial as well as 2 others trying to host my project using Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=bash#clone-the-sample-app **I managed to host the sample web app used in the tutorial, but could not host my own project**

**I keep getting "Server Error 500". I've spent around 36 hours trying to fix the problem.**

1. I checked the application logs - nothing
2. I checked the kudu/scm logs - nothing
3. I looked under "App Service logs" and checked the ftp logs - nothing
4. **I checked to see if all the files had been uploaded** at this location "<>.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/"  The staticfiles successfully uploaded.
5. **I went to "Web SSH"** and installed all the dependencies** "pip install -r requirements.txt"
   then did **"python manage.py runserver"  AND NO ERRORS, but it did not want to connect to "127.0.0.1:8000" or "localhost:8000" ???**
6. I spend around 6 hours searching for answers - tried everything - nothing worked
7. **WEBSITES_PORT set to 8000** (tried different ports and removed this setting after no luck)
8. **I changed DEBUG to False and True - didn't work**
9. I did set all the necessary environment variables (eg, DB_HOST, DB_PASSWORD ...)
10. The App Service plan is F1 (free)
11. **I went to all the pages on my web app and got server error 500 on all the pages except when logging into admin, after logging into admin I got the error again.**

**Possible Solutions I thought might work**

1. I might be missing an important "Application setting" ???
2. One of the dependencies might be causing the problem - but I highly doubt it
3. I dont know pls help sir

**This was about what the logs kept saying**

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

2020-06-24T08:28:13.331Z INFO  - Starting **container** for site
2020-06-24T08:28:13.331Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 5480:**8000** --name forexflowcom_0_136ed024 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=forexflowcom -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=forexflowcom.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=9072c805cf2bc663ced034398777a5d5f6115a51e64a73b6fc69b73f64c8660e -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/python:3.7_20200101.1

2020-06-24T08:28:16.751Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to **container** forexflowcom_0_136ed024 for site forexflowcom
2020-06-24T08:28:28.970Z INFO  - **Container** forexflowcom_0_136ed024 for site forexflowcom initialized **successfully** and is ready to serve requests.
2020-06-24T09:34:28.003Z INFO  - Starting **container** for site
2020-06-24T09:34:28.010Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 5757:**8000** --name forexflowcom_1_86357e3d -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=forexflowcom -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=forexflowcom.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=9072c805cf2bc663ced034398777a5d5f6115a51e64a73b6fc69b73f64c8660e -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/python:3.7_20200101.1

2020-06-24T09:34:31.507Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to **container** forexflowcom_1_86357e3d for site forexflowcom
2020-06-24T09:34:49.002Z INFO  - **Container** forexflowcom_1_86357e3d for site forexflowcom initialized **successfully** and is ready to serve requests.
2020-06-24T09:38:04.238Z INFO  - Starting **container** for site
2020-06-24T09:38:04.240Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 7958:**8000** --name forexflowcom_2_79f5bea0 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=forexflowcom -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=forexflowcom.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=9072c805cf2bc663ced034398777a5d5f6115a51e64a73b6fc69b73f64c8660e -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/python:3.7_20200101.1

2020-06-24T09:38:08.317Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to **container** forexflowcom_2_79f5bea0 for site forexflowcom
2020-06-24T09:38:23.838Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for **container** forexflowcom_2_79f5bea0. Elapsed time = 15.5210597 sec
2020-06-24T09:38:41.054Z INFO  - **Container** forexflowcom_2_79f5bea0 for site forexflowcom initialized **successfully** and is ready to serve requests.

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT // EDIT // EDIT // EDIT // EDIT**
I found The solution
in settings.py I had: 
try: 
from .local_settings import * 
except ImportError: 
print("No local file, your in production") 

after removing this It worked